# Open a form action in a facebox... (php href and form action)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Someone now how i can open this in a facebox ? (all is in php fonction)

```
 echo "< font class=text16bu-ongreen>&nbsp;".lang("Add Payment")."&nbsp;< /font>< br>< br>";

if ($balance > 0) {
reset($paymentplugins);
while (list($key, $plugin) = each($paymentplugins)) {

echo "< form action=$plugin.php?func=add method=post>< input type=hidden name=currenttotal value= \"".mf("$balance")."\" >";

echo "< input type=hidden name=cfirstname value=\"$cfirstname\" >";
echo "< input type=hidden name=ccompany value=\"$ccompany\" >";
echo "< input type=hidden name=caddress value=\"$caddress\"  >";
echo "< input type=hidden name=caddress2 value=\"$caddress2\">";
echo "< input type=hidden name=ccity value=\"$ccity\">";
echo "< input type=hidden name=cstate value=\"$cstate\">";
echo "< input type=hidden name=czip value=\"$czip\">";
echo "< input type=hidden name=cphone value=\"$cphone\">";
echo "< input type=hidden name=cemail value=\"$cemail\">";

echo "< input type=submit class=button value=\"$plugin\"></form>";
```

In the rest of the script, the facebox is call by rel=facebox but here i don't know how to do...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your code in a `<div id="paymentform" style="display:none"></div>`

After that, use facebox to open that div.

```
<a href="#paymentform" rel="facebox">add payment</a>
```

Comment: That's great. I'm glad that worked out for you. Don't forget to select my answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer !

I do something little bit ugly but it's work like this :

```
$currenttotal=$balance;

if ($balance > 0) {
reset($paymentplugins);
while (list($key, $plugin) = each($paymentplugins)) {


echo "<a href=$plugin.php?func=add&currenttotal=$currenttotal&cfirstname=$cfirstname&ccompany=$ccompany&caddress=$caddress&caddress2=$caddress2&ccity=$ccity&cstate=$cstate&czip=$czip&cphone=$cphone&cemail=$cemail class=button rel=facebox>$plugin </a>";

}
```

Thank you for your help !